# Adding space above the first tableview section

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How do I add space above the first tableview section? You can see that the first section: "A", doesn't have the right above it. Here's an image: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QRuL_aoSQNbg-SLlrcAzcQGT1L7gBCTgg-ji-XTHXjY/edit?usp=sharing
Tried changing UITableview content offset in viewDidLoad, but that didn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:I solved it like this: (NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
        return 40;
    } //otherwise handle other cells

Comment: If you need to do that to fix the issue then you are simply working around some other problem you have. You should fix the actual problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` better use `contentInset` property of your table view as described in ["Creating and Configuring Scroll Views"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html) of Apple developer's library.
Simply put this code in a place where you initialize or configure your table view:

```
CGFloat topInset = 10; //change this value as needed
tableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsets(top:topInset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

**UPDATE for Swift 4**

```
let topInset: CGFloat = 10
myTableView.contentInset.top = topInset
```